# Importing CIFAR-10 Data set in F#

Tags: f#, dataset, computer-vision

I try to import the CIFAR-10 dataset "https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html" in F#, there are three formats; python, matlab(MAT) and binary(bin),respectively. Please feel free to comment of how to import the dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use the binary version of the datasets. The description on the CIFAR page is quite clear:

> The first byte is the label of the first image, which is a number in the range 0-9. The next 3072 bytes are the values of the pixels of the image. The first 1024 bytes are the red channel values, the next 1024 the green, and the final 1024 the blue. The values are stored in row-major order, so the first 32 bytes are the red channel values of the first row of the image.

You have not specified in any way *how* you want to import the dataset, here's what I think will make sense:

- Extract the 6 batches from the `.tar.gz` file
- For each batch:
- Create a binary reader
- Read the byte that contains the label
- Instantiate a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` of size 32 x 32
- Loop over the rows and columns of the image, read a byte from the file, set it in the red channel of the image
- Repeat that with the green and blue channel.
- Store in your final format (for example, a directory with individual PNG files)

Comment: Thank you. I shall try it as soon as possible.

Comment: To save time, I converted MAT file to CSV (label,pixel0,pixel1,pixel2, .... ,pixel3071) Thank for you advice.